# Joomla: mod_login parameters not showing up in administrator backend

Tags: php, joomla

I am trying to change the Name/username parameter value to "Name" in the mod_login parameters. But for my Joomla installation (Joomla! 1.5.23), only a few parameters are shown (Caching + Encrypt Login Form).

Is there a way to display more parameters in the backend? If not, where can I edit the parameter? Is there an ini file somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually modules parameters are stored in an XML file within the directory with the same name as the module, under the 'modules' folder (if admin modules, those are under 'administrator/').
In that file are stored the parameters used by a module, which are shown in the module configuration in Back-End.

As for mod_login, those params are not editable, but if you open the mod_login.php file  (under administrator/modules/mod_login/) you'll find the html relative to that form.

```
<p id="form-login-username">
        <label for="modlgn_username"><?php echo JText::_('Username'); ?></label>
        <input name="username" id="modlgn_username" type="text" class="inputbox" size="15" />
    </p>

    <p id="form-login-password">
        <label for="modlgn_passwd"><?php echo JText::_('Password'); ?></label>
        <input name="passwd" id="modlgn_passwd" type="password" class="inputbox" size="15" />
    </p>
```

Add a `value="(your value here)"` and it set.

Alternatively, if you want to do things well done, open the XML file and add

```
<param name="name_default" type="text" default="Name" label="Default value for username" description="Default value for username" />
```

And in `mod_login.php` you call this parameter with

```
 $default_value = $params->get('name_default');
```

And just put into the form:

```
<input name="username" id="modlgn_username" type="text" value="<?php echo $default_value;?>" class="inputbox" size="15" />
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me helpful pointers, although I had some problems implementing your suggestions. I ended up editing the file default.php located in the directory \templates\your-template\html\mod_login, as suggested by imanickam at http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=431&t=658341

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I forgot that some modules are overridden by templates...Anyway, they all work like this. This one I showed is the default joomla one, and is very simple. Complex modules has TMPL/default.php as 'view', HELPER.PHP as 'model' and MOD_xxxx.php as 'controller', but params are managed like this, through the XML file